# Mesh extraction: which face connected to which objects

Tags: mesh

While exporting the mesh of a geometry, is it possible to also extract the information on which face is connected to which objects.

For instance, consider two cubes touching each other on one of their faces. After meshing, some faces will delimit the boundaries between: 1) cube1 and the "exterior", 2) cube2 and the "exterior", and 3) cube1 and cube2. That's the information I am trying to extract. Is it possible to do that in Blender ? If yes, how ?

Edit: 
The meshes generated in Blender are meant to be used in an homemade surface integral equations electromagnetic solver. This solver needs to know the position of each vertices of the mesh but also which face is connected to which objects, hence my question.

Comment: Your question is not well explanatory... What will be the usefulness of the extracted information in the export?

Comment: Since you already know the Information you want to extract, you can write the information in a notepad

Comment: Assuming OP and suggested editor are one and same user, ...?